# Python renaming file

Tags: python, file, file-rename

I'm renaming file using `os.rename(old filename,new_filename)`

I'm getting permission error[winError 32] the process cannot access the file because it is being used by other process

I tried to close file using command os.close(old_file), I'm getting `AttributeError: str object has no attribute close`

Comment: Based on your description, the old_file is probably used by __another__ program, not the one that renames it.

Comment: The message `AttributeError: str object has no attribute close` makes me think you have assigned a string to a variable `os`, which might be overriding the intended `os` module import. You can also try closing the file through the file browser. That might give you more information about what file's holding it open.

Comment: The argument to `os.close()` should be the file descriptor returned by `os.open()`, not a filename.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your issue is without some screenshots but if you're using Juypter Notebook I would try refreshing the kernel. I produced the same error but that fixed the issue. It could also be that a file is open that should not be.

It could also be that you are using **os.open()** and **os.close()** incorrectly.

```
import os
import os

old_name = r"\stuffs\texted.txt"
new_name =r"\stuffs\texteds.txt"

os.rename(old_name,new_name)

fd = os.open(new_name,os.O_RDONLY)
os.close(fd)
```

**os.open()**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_open.htm

Python method `open()` opens the file file and set various flags according to flags and possibly its mode according to mode.The default mode is 0777 (octal), and the current umask value is first masked out.

**os.close()**

> Note: This function is intended for low-level I/O and must be applied to a file descriptor as returned by `os.open()` or `pipe()`. To close a “file object” returned by the built-in function `open()` or by `popen()` or `fdopen()`, use its `close()` method.

Comment: to add onto this, its generally recommended to use a context manager when opening files to avoid closing issues: `with open(path/to/file) as f:`

Comment: This won't solve the problem, which is that something else is holding the file open.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, It's more than likely something holding the file open. If they tried to use `os.close() ` to close the file then I think that could be one of the issues.